# How to Iterate & Count Each Categorical Value Based on Some Condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining, data-wrangling

I was working on a dataset & I want to iterate through each value to find the count of **job** & **marital status** based on the **deposit**

Example:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your data. Rather, post small sample datasets with desired output.

Comment: It's a practice data which I have taken from the Kaggle itself so I guess there's not an issue with that?

Comment: I will much more likely spend time on your question and try things when I can simply copy+paste from your post, rather than searching the interwebs for the source of your data.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @t.novaes I want to find the count by iterating each row based on some condition & then group them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the pandas' [groupyby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operation. Let's say your data is stored in a data frame `df`:

```
df.groupby(by = ['job','marital', 'deposit']).count()
```

This will return the possible 'job', 'marital' and 'deposit' combinations, and how many elements you find under these groups.

I hope it helps!

Cheers,

T

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can use this which will give me an output that is not exactly the same but giving enough insights for the analysis purpose with better clarity.

```
bank_data[bank_data['deposit'] == 'no'].groupby(['marital', 'job']).count().iloc[:,-1:]
bank_data[bank_data['deposit'] == 'yes'].groupby(['marital', 'job']).count().iloc[:,-1:]
```